# TSO - Insert blank page

Tags: sorting, tso

Is there a way in TSO SORT to add a blank page after a certain string in the file ? Any help much appreciated. I need this extra page so that the output splits properly when being printed.

Comment: Could you please clarify? Do you mean SORT as an ISPF EDIT primary command, or invoking SORT in the foreground, or as part of a REXX/CLIST? Could you describe the entire process where SORT is used?

Answer (score 0):

The SORT is being used in some JCL as below :-

```
//WSMFDST5 EXEC PGM=SORT,COND=(4,LT)
//SYSOUT   DD   SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD   DSN=JLP.TEST.PARMLIB(WSMFD32C),DISP=SHR
//SORTIN   DD   DSN=WSM.TEMP.WSMPRM,DISP=(OLD)
//SORTOUT  DD   DSN=WSM.TEST.WSMPRM.WSMFF.GDG.NEW(0),DISP=(OLD,KEEP)
```

So, I was hoping to code something in JLP.TEST.PARMLIB(WSMFD32C)that adds a blank page when a certain string is found.

Many thanks